# Nav2 - global_planner does not avoid obstacles

Tags: ros, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am tunning nav2 parameters for a rectangular robot, when I send a goal that requires obstacle avoidance the planner does not avoid the obstacle, here is my param file and screenshot. Thanks for help.

[image: image description]

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "differential"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.01 
    update_min_d: 0.2 
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan_front
    map_topic: map

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: "map"
    robot_base_frame: "base_link"
    odom_topic: /odom
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 5.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugin: "goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      stateful: True
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 1.5
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 1.0
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "ObstacleFootprint", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"] # ObstacleFootprint pour notre robot (non circulaire)
      ObstacleFootprint.scale: 0.02 # meme chose
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: "map"
      robot_base_frame: "base_link"
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 5
      height: 5
      resolution: 0.05
      map_topic: "map"
      origin_x: -24.9
      origin_y: -24.9
      footprint_padding: 0.01
      footprint: "[[-0.7874, -0.381], [-0.7874, 0.381], [0.8636, 0.381], [0.8636, -0.381]]"
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan_front
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      footprint_padding: 0.01
      footprint: "[[-0.7874, -0.381], [-0.7874, 0.381], [0.8636, 0.381], [0.8636, -0.381]]"
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan_front
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        enabled: true
        subscribe_to_updates: true
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: "map.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5000
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "back_up", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    back_up:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378736/nav2---global_planner-does-not-avoid-obstacles/) by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2021-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avzmpy](https://answers.ros.org/users/56476/avzmpy/) on 2021-05-21**:
I've experienced the same behavior. There is a major bug in Foxy version at least. Robot plans straight through obstacles because the costmap at that point in time is completely empty for some reason. Modifying source code to check if that's the case solves the problem, but i would suggest switching to more recent version of nav2

**Comment by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on 2021-05-21**:
@avzmpy thanks, but that's weird because turtlebot3 simulation is working fine !! is there a ticket for that bug on work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the comments above suggest, its a bug in Foxy that had been patched in main or newer (Galactic). The solution was a bit involved and required breaking ABI so we could not backport it to Foxy as is.

I’d be more than happy to point a user in the right direction to see if they can find a non-ABI breaking way of solving this issue for Foxy.

The root cause is the costmap clearing recovery will clear the costmaps before the next costmap update cycle, resulting in an empty global costmap to plan straight through obstacles.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nedo99](https://answers.ros.org/users/70099/nedo99/) on 2021-10-05**:
Is there a maybe patch for it for Foxy?